# Script to watch an application status icon

Tags: xfce, system-tray, notification-area

I am looking for a bash/python script to watch an application status icon in notification area and change it whene active/inactive/idle/busy.. (like dropbox status icons).
im running Ubuntu 16.04 Xfce 4.12